# Batch rename file with regex: remove prefix

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, rename, batch-rename

I have files `<uuid>_CS_Filename`, and i want replace `uuid_` => with ".*?_" to "".

How can I do this?

So, for;

```bash
1557acc7f3cd5d1538b71fe77bcf9ec0_My_filename_ch101.pdf
```

I want:

```bash
My_filename_ch101.pdf
```

I don't want to install some 3rd party packages; I searched the internet and only found `brew install rename`.

Comment: `brew install rename` is a good start. Please read its manual and try for yourself. If you then encounter a problem, come back here showing what you have tried and your specific problem. Then we will be your help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```bash
filename="1557acc7f3cd5d1538b71fe77bcf9ec0_My_filename_ch101.pdf"
newname=$(echo $filename | sed -e 's/^[a-z0-9]*_//g')
# newname is "My_filename_ch101.pdf"
```

Assume the files to rename are all in current directory:

```bash
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed -e 's/^[a-z0-9]*_//g')"
done
```

Comment: You shouldn't parse ls in a script - more appropriate would be `for f in *`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs . Quotes are also important when variables contain pathnames (e.g. `"$f"` instead of `$f`).

Comment: Thanks and the script has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Using `cut`:

```
cut -d '_' -f 2- <<<"1557acc7f3cd5d1538b71fe77bcf9ec0_My_filename_ch101.pdf"
```

Sample usage:

```
$ touch 1557acc7f3cd5d1538b71fe77bcf9ec0_My_filename_ch101.pdf
$ fname="1557acc7f3cd5d1538b71fe77bcf9ec0_My_filename_ch101.pdf"
$ ls $fname
1557acc7f3cd5d1538b71fe77bcf9ec0_My_filename_ch101.pdf
$ mv "$fname" $(cut -d '_' -f 2- <<<"$fname")
$ ls *My*
My_filename_ch101.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

Using bash parameter expansions:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in * ; do
  [[ -e "${f}" ]] || continue
  mv "${f}" "${f#*_}"
done
```